# Why getcwd fails with errno ENOENT

Tags: c++, centos, ubuntu-16.04, getcwd

I'm using the [getcwd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) function to retrieve the current working directory of my application.
In some cases it fails and errno is ENOENT. I call getcwd from different threads, but serially and sometimes I face with ENOENT, but I don't know why.
The link above says that ENOENT means that "The current working directory has been unlinked." but the directory exists.

Here is a snippet of the function I use:

UPDATE: Code updated with advice from @Aganju and @molbdnilo:

```
std::string get_working_dir()
{
    char buf[PATH_MAX];
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    char * result = getcwd(buf, sizeof(buf));
    std::string working_path = buf;
    // Check for possible errors.
    if (result == NULL)
    {        
        switch (errno)
        {
            case EACCES:
                break;
            case EFAULT:
                break;
            case EINVAL:
                break;
            case ENAMETOOLONG:
                break;
            case ENOENT:
            {
                if (working_path.empty())
                {
                    const char* pwd = getenv("PWD");
                    working_path = (pwd) ? pwd : "";
                }
                break;
            }
            case ERANGE:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return working_path;
    }
}
```

In case I face ENOENT, I retrieve the "PWD" environment variable because I work on CentOS 5.11 and Ubuntu 16.04, and when getcwd fails on CentOS it returns an empty buffer.

UPDATE:

I have noticed that the call from the main thread does not fail, but when I call the function from another thread it fails and errno is ENOENT.

Comment: Run `strace` on your process, possibly with the `-f` flag, and observe which systemcall returns `ENOENT`. This will be your first clue as to what could be going on.

Comment: You need to check the return value of `getcwd` first. `errno` is meaningless unless `getcwd` returns a null pointer.

Comment: I checked for NULL as you and @Aganju recommended. On CentOS 5 `getcwd` returns NULL and errno is ENOENT. I'm going to update the example code.
One thing I have noticed is that as my app is multithreaded, the calls that fails with ENOENT are the ones that are not called from the main thread.

Answer (score 3):

As [molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo) said, you need to check the return value first.

The manual you link to states:

> [...] On failure, these functions return NULL, and errno is set to
>   indicate the error.[...]

In other words, if there is *no* failure, `errno` is *not* set, and contains whatever it contained from whatever call happened before, maybe a long time before, which is without meaning in this context.

Use something like `char * result = getcwd(buf, sizeof(buf));`, and then check for `if (result == NULL) { switch (errno) ...`, etc.

Comment: I checked for NULL as you recommended.
On CentOS 5 getcwd returns NULL and errno is ENOENT. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen in the following situation, which we can illustrate with a multi-process sequence diagram, using shell script syntax:

```
process A                     process B
$ cd ~                        $ cd ~
user $ mkdir foo            
user $ cd foo
                              user $ rm -rf foo              
user/foo $ pwd
/home/user/foo
user/foo $ cd .
cd: error retrieving current
directory: getcwd: cannot access
parent directories: No such file or directory
```

Every process in a Unix-like operating system has a current working directory , which holds a reference to an object in the file system. That object cannot be reclaimed as free space until the process drops that current directory.

Above, Process A continues to hold on to the directory which **used to be** `~/foo`. That **path** no longer exists in the directory structure, but the directory **object** continues to exist.

The `getcwd` system call realizes this: it sees that the current working directory the calling process is not linked into the directory structure and hence has no path, so it reports an error.

The `pwd` shell command works because it just regurgitates a piece of datum that the shell knows about without calling `getcwd`; but when we try `cd .`, an error occurs (reproduced with Bash on a GNU/Linux system; results may vary).

Comment: My app is single process but multithreaded. Could this be happening anyway? Threads are supposed to share the working directory.

Comment: It's a misfeature of POSIX that the `chdir` system call has a process-wide side effect. In practice, what it means that a multithreaded process should establish a working directory at start up and not touch it again.  Also, functions which implicitly call `chdir` have to be avoided like `nftw` and such.